# I want to add column sort links to the Index page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting

I am trying to add a column sorting link to the "due date" column in my web application, and I am having trouble getting it to work correctly. Currently, this is my code in the controller where I have defined the switch statement to determine how the user wants to sort:

```
 var items = from s in db.Items
                    select s;

        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "DueDate" ? "duedate_desc" : "DueDate";

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "duedate_desc":
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.DueDate);
                break;
            case "DueDate":
                items = items.OrderBy(s => s.DueDate);
                break;
            default:
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.DueDate);
                break;
```

In the index view here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ItemDescription)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Quantity)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Price)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Due Date", "Index", new 
        {
            sortOrder=ViewBag.DateSortParm,

        })
```

Lastly, this is where I believe I am getting my error, back in the controller, when I return the View I have this code:

```
int pageSize = 15;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        pageNumber = page == null ? (ViewBag.pageData == null ? 1 : (int)ViewBag.pageData) : page.Value;
        ViewBag.pageData = page;
        ViewBag.searchBy = searchBy;
        ViewBag.search = search;
        return View(items.OrderBy(i => i.ItemId).ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
```

I have to have the .OrderBy to get the view to render, otherwise I get a "skip" method error. Is this causing the problem as to why the column sorting links won't work correctly? Any Possible Solutions?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question. I had to remove the .OrderBy clause.